# Using javascript to get all Rows from a grid, not just rows on visible page

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have added 3 buttons to the toolbar in order to process records from an existing CRM form: "Process Selected Records", "Process All Records on Page", "Process All Records from All Pages".

Dealing with "Selected records" and "All records on Page" is fairly simple as the records can be accessed with settings in the RibbonDiffXml CommandDefinition:

```
    CrmParameter Value="SelectedControlAllItemReferences"
    CrmParameter Value="SelectedControlSelectedItemReferences"
```

I'm looking for a way, with javascript, to access all records from all pages of the form's grid when the user presses the toolbar button that I have added. I'm quite sure that those records would not exist in the client's page and that I'd have to retrieve them from the server somehow, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 0):

So you are correct, the records would not exist on the client.

Best way to do this with CRM 2011 is a REST call which you can easily perform using JavaScript to query the server for the required records.

You may find these links useful.

[Use the REST Endpoint for Web Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334279(v=crm.5).aspx)

[Getting started with CRM 2011 JavaScript REST (OData) Web Service Calls](https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/getting-started-with-crm-2011-javascript-rest-odata-web-service-calls/)

Comment: Thank you for your input. You're certainly correct that I'll have to use REST to retrieve a result set to process. What I'm stuck on is how exactly I go about duplicating the result set that the user is already looking at. I have no idea if I have any avenue to access that information or not. Thanks again!

Comment: If you know which view they are using, e.g. its fixed, you can craft your query to perform the same search.